# Is there a way to enable "Services" menu for an application?

Tags: services

Almost every OSx Application has a service menú like this:

[image]

But I've found that my [HipChat for MAC](https://www.hipchat.com/mac) doesn't have. I don't know if there is a setting that will enable this menu or it is something related to the way the application was created.

Comment: Are you talking about the Services menu, or the group of options - hide, hide other, and show?

Comment: He speaks of Services.

Comment: Services, sorry the selected "Show All" could be confused in the screnshot but I am very specific about the Service Menu in the description, thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a Keyboard Shortcut for the application in System Preferences/Keyboard/Keyboard  Shortcuts/Application Shortcuts ? Odd that HipChat didn't install any Services, I find every app I install is allowed to do so by default, and one must go find and uncheck them. Bad design, Apple. bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the way the application is created. More [about Services in Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).

I suggest you direct HipChat Devs to this page.